# Como criar templates com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se é possível (e como fazer, se for) *templates* com *Javascript*. Assim como o *Facelets* no *JSF*, onde cria-se uma página modelo e as demais seguem o que foi pré-estabelecido.

Se alguém puder indicar algum material, agradeço bastante!

Comment: Como Assim? seguem o que foi Pré-Estabelecido? Você está falando de Orientação a àbjetos?

Comment: Algo como [templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates) no AngularJS ?

Comment: Desculpe, é que eu não sei muito bem como explicar isso. 

Tipo, em JSF tem os facelets permitem que a gente crie um template de página (com o topo e rodapé, por exemplo). E nas demais é só chamar esse template e colocar o corpo da página. Ou seja, não preciso ficar copiando o topo e rodapé em todas as páginas.

Comment: Bootstrap é em javascript, css e html5. Tem muitos componentes la

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com  [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) você poderá criar templates em js com facilidade!

**Veja um exemplo de sua syntax/Utilização:**

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Utilizando `{{template}}` para realizar as suas marcações.

**Populando o template.**

```
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
var html    = template(context);
```

**Resultado:**

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>My New Post</h1>
  <div class="body">
    This is my first post!
  </div>
</div>
```

Outro framework que pode realizar isto é o AngularJS, ele é muito completo possui:

- Two-way Data binding
- Injeção de Dependências
- Criação de diretivas (Extensão do HTML)  <- Template
- Modularização e reuso (Controllers, Services e Filters)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar o próprio AngularJS para modularizar a página. É possível que você separe a marcação, conteúdo e lógica de cada parte do seu web app individualmente.

Você pode ver a documentação disso em:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Também é possível utilizar soluções em específico só para template, como é o caso do mustache e outras engines de template para js. Confira o funcionamento de alguns em:
http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396

se for simplesmente para separar o header e o footer, é possível incluir o angularjs na página e utilizar a seguinte semântica:

```
<div ng-include="'includes/header.html'"></div> 

<!-- Conteúdo da página -->

<div ng-include="'includes/footer.html'"></div>
```